# How to use CUDA tex1DFetch with cudaTextureObject_t?

Tags: cuda, textures

I was working with texture references when I noticed they were deprecated, I tried to update my test function to work with the 'new' bindless texture objects with tex1Dfetch but was not able to produce the same results.

I'm currently exploring the use of texture memory to speed up my aho-corasick implementation; I was able to get `tex1D()` working with texture references, however, I noticed they were deprecated and decided to use texture objects instead.

I'm getting some immensely weird behaviour with the kernels when I try to use the results in any way; I can do `results[tidx] = tidx;` without any issues, but `results[tidx] = temp + 1;` only ever returns the value of `temp` not `temp * 3` or any other numerical test involving `temp`.

I can see no logical reason for this behaviour, and the documentation examples look similar enough that I can't see where I've gone wrong.

I've already read CUDA tex1Dfetch() wrong behaviour and New CUDA Texture Object — getting wrong data in 2D case but neither seem related to the issue I am having.

Just in case it makes a difference; I am am using CUDA release 10.0, V10.0.130 with an Nvidia GTX 980ti.

```
#include <iostream>

__global__ void test(cudaTextureObject_t tex ,int* results){
    int tidx = threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned temp = tex1Dfetch<unsigned>(tex, threadIdx.x);
    results[tidx] = temp * 3;
}

int main(){
    int *host_arr;
    const int host_arr_size = 8;

    // Create and populate host array
    std::cout << "Host:" << std::endl;
    cudaMallocHost(&host_arr, host_arr_size*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < host_arr_size; ++i){
        host_arr[i] = i * 2;
        std::cout << host_arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Create resource description
    struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeLinear;
    resDesc.res.linear.devPtr = &host_arr;
    resDesc.res.linear.sizeInBytes = host_arr_size*sizeof(unsigned);
    resDesc.res.linear.desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<unsigned>();
    // Create texture description
    struct cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
    texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
    // Create texture
    cudaTextureObject_t tex;
    cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex, &resDesc, &texDesc, NULL);

    // Allocate results array
    int * result_arr;
    cudaMalloc(&result_arr, host_arr_size*sizeof(unsigned));

    // launch test kernel
    test<<<1, host_arr_size>>>(tex, result_arr);

    // fetch results
    std::cout << "Device:" << std::endl;
    cudaMemcpy(host_arr, result_arr, host_arr_size*sizeof(unsigned), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // print results
    for (int i = 0; i < host_arr_size; ++i){
        std::cout << host_arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Tidy Up
    cudaDestroyTextureObject(tex);
    cudaFreeHost(host_arr);
    cudaFree(result_arr);
}
```

I expected the above to work similarly to the below (which does work):

```
texture<int, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> tex_ref;
cudaArray* cuda_array;

__global__ void test(int* results){
    const int tidx = threadIdx.x;
    results[tidx] = tex1D(tex_ref, tidx) * 3;
}

int main(){
    int *host_arr;
    int host_arr_size = 8;

    // Create and populate host array
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&host_arr, host_arr_size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < host_arr_size; ++i){
        host_arr[i] = i * 2;
        std::cout << host_arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // bind to texture
    cudaChannelFormatDesc cuDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc <int >();
    cudaMallocArray(&cuda_array, &cuDesc, host_arr_size);
    cudaMemcpyToArray(cuda_array, 0, 0, host_arr , host_arr_size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaBindTextureToArray(tex_ref , cuda_array);
    // Allocate results array
    int * result_arr;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&result_arr, host_arr_size*sizeof(int));

    // launch kernel
    test<<<1, host_arr_size>>>(result_arr);

    // fetch results
    cudaMemcpy(host_arr, result_arr, host_arr_size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    // print results
    for (int i = 0; i < host_arr_size; ++i){
        std::cout << host_arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Tidy Up
    cudaUnbindTexture(tex_ref);
    cudaFreeHost(host_arr);
    cudaFreeArray(cuda_array);
    cudaFree(result_arr);
}
```

Expected results:

```
Host:
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
Device:
0
6
12
18
24
30
36
42
```

Actual results:

```
Host:
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
Device:
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
```

Does anyone know what on earth is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUDA API function calls return error codes. You want to check these error codes. Especially when something is clearly going wrong *somewhere*…

You use the the same array to store the initial array data as well as to receive the result from the device. Your kernel launch fails with an illegal address error because you do not have a valid texture object. You do not have a valid texture object because the creation of your texture object failed. The first API call right after the kernel launch is the `cudaMemcpy()` to get the results back. Since there was an error during the kernel launch, [`cudaMemcpy()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8) will fail, returning the most recent error instead of performing the copy. As a result, the contents of your `host_arr` buffer are unchanged and you just end up displaying the original input data again.

The reson why creation of your texture object failed is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT_1g16ac75814780c3a16e4c63869feb9ad3) (emphasis mine):

> If cudaResourceDesc::resType is set to cudaResourceTypeLinear, cudaResourceDesc::res::linear::devPtr must be set to **a valid device pointer**, that is aligned to cudaDeviceProp::textureAlignment. […]

A texture object cannot reference host memory. The problem in your code lies here:

```
resDesc.res.linear.devPtr = &host_arr;
```

You need to allocate a buffer in decive memory, e.g., using `cudaMalloc()`, copy your data there, and create a texture object that refers to that device buffer.

Furthermore, your `texDesc` is not initialized properly. In your case, it should be sufficient to just zero-initialize it:

```
struct cudaTextureDesc texDesc = {};
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thanks for the tips! I saw the memset initialization in the "CUDA Pro Tip: Kepler Texture Objects Improve Performance and Flexibility" example so thought it was something needed.

Answer (score -1):

4 steps:

1. declare

`texture<unsigned char,1,cudaReadmodeElementType> tex1;`

2. bind

`cudaBindTexture(0,tex1,dev_A);`

3. fetch/read via index

`tex1Dfetch(tex1,2);`

4. unbind

`cudaUnbindTexture(tex1)；`